# How to keep both files from a “both added” merge conflict?

Tags: git, merge, merge-conflict-resolution, git-merge-conflict

I want to merge a branch which added a file that I have added as well:

```
Unmerged paths:
  (use "git add <file>..." to mark resolution)
        both added:      file
```

I want to resolve this conflict by renaming my version of `file` to `other_file` while keeping the version of the other branch.

My solution would be:

```
git checkout --ours file
mv file other_file
git checkout --theirs file
git add file other_file
```

Is there an easier or more direct solution?

Answer (score 1):

I recreated this kind of conflict:

```
$ git merge b1
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in newfile
Auto-merging newfile
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

and indeed, there's Git's attempt to merge the files in the work-tree:

```
$ cat newfile   
<<<<<<< HEAD
different contents - add a file
||||||| merged common ancestors
=======
add a file
>>>>>>> b1
```

Your method will work fine.  This one is not much shorter, and has potential glitches with end-of-line modifications depending on your Git vintage:

```
$ git show :2:newfile > other_file   # extract --ours version, to new name
$ git checkout --theirs newfile
Updated 1 path from the index
$ git add newfile other_file
$ it status -s
M  newfile
A  other_file
```

As the (short) `status` shows, the two files are now ready to be committed.  Their contents are:

```
$ cat newfile
add a file
$ cat other_file
different contents - add a file
```

Note that `git show` does not run smudge filters and does not do end-of-line conversions, at least in older versions of Git (Git has acquired the ability to do text conversions and maybe `git show` does them by default now—I have not tested this).